# Sonata mongodb admin bundle filter by reference

Tags: mongodb, sonata-admin, symfony, sonata

I have document with

`/** @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="NewsTag") */
    private $tags;`

relation.

In my sonata admin i want to filter list by tag. I try to use

`$datagridMapper->add('tags', null, array(), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))`

as in documentation, but have an error

`Could not load type "document"`

Anybody know why?

UPD: stack trace

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "document"
at n/a
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php line 87

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry->getType('document')
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 83

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('value', 'document', null, array('required' => false, 'class' => 'AppBundle\Document\NewsTag', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 106

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->create('value', 'document', array('required' => false, 'class' => 'AppBundle\Document\NewsTag', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 267

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->resolveChildren()
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 215

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 221

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 11085

at Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\Datagrid->buildPager()
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 11189

at Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\Datagrid->getForm()
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/CRUDController.php line 105

at Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController->listAction()
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(LanguagesAdminController), 'listAction'), array())
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 139

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 62

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 169

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/web/app_dev.php line 30
```

Comment: I think the second argument, `null`, is guessed as "document". Try replacing it with `dacument` to confirm that. If the error message speaks about `dacument`, my theory is right. Also, you should provide a stack trace (as text, see the bottom of the page)

Comment: Yes. It guessed as `document`. I already find place in source code where. Question is what should by the second argument. I tried `doctrine_mongo_model`, but it also guessed as `document`/

Comment: And with the fourth argument ? I always mix them up…

Comment: Ok, now i have another error. I try `$datagridMapper->add('tags', null, [], 'sonata_type_model', ['multiple' => true, 'property' => 'name', 'by_reference' => false])` and error is `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList\ModelChoiceLoader::__construct() must implement interface Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\ModelManagerInterface, null given, called in /var/www/meteoprog-site-s3/var/cache/dev/classes.php on line 13150 and defined`

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to filter with sonata_type_model probably a bug hapens. You don't have modelManager in ChoiceField.
But you can manually add it in configureDatagridFilters like this:

```
   $datagridMapper
        ->add('tags', null, [], 'sonata_type_model',
            [
                'model_manager' => $datagridMapper->getAdmin()->getModelManager(), 
                'property' => 'name', 
                'multiple' => true, 
                'by_reference' => false
            ]);
```